# Leibniz Integral Rule

Tags: calculus, integration

I know this form of the Leibniz's Integral Rule

> $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)}f(t) dt=f(h(x)) h'(x)-f(g(x))g'(x).$$

But how to use it when I get questions like:

[image]

Comment: I don't have a very nice handwriting so, please tell me if you are not able to understand.

Comment: These are of exactly the same form... just replace $f$ by $fj$ or $f/j$ everywhere in the rule you have.

Answer (score 2):

set $u(t)=f(t)j(t)$, and then use the Leibniz rlue for the following instead: $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)}u(t)dt$$